# What is the difference between `stream_from` and `stream_for` in ActionCable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

The descriptions [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/actioncable/ActionCable/Channel/Streams#stream_for-instance_method) seem to imply that `stream_for` is used only when passing in a record, but overall the documentation is rather vague.  Can anyone explain the differences between `stream_from` and `stream_for` and why would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`stream_for` is simply a wrapper method of `stream_from` with ease.

When you need a stream that is related to a specific model, `stream_for` automatically generates broadcasting from the model and channel for you.

Let's assume you have a `chat_room` instance of `ChatRoom` class,

```
stream_from "chat_rooms:#{chat_room.to_gid_param}"
```

or

```
stream_for chat_room # equivalent with stream_from "chat_rooms:Z2lkOi8vVGVzdEFwcC9Qb3N0LzE"
```

the two lines of code does the same thing.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/lib/action_cable/channel/streams.rb

Comment: What is the point of the `to_gid_param` part ? Couldn't you just say `chat_room_#{params[:chat_room_id]}` ?

Comment: Is it just for encoding an arbitrary string into a valid non-whitespace string ? Or is there any other idea behind it ?

Comment: `stream_for is used when there is a particular record (or record and association) we want updates about. Under the hood, Action Cable is generating a unique string for that record or that record and its association and then calls the stream_for [sic -- probably should be 'stream_from'] method.`Source: https://www.sitepoint.com/action-cable-and-websockets-an-in-depth-tutorial/

Comment: gid_param is hard to predict. It blocks an attacker who give random ids to get streams.

Comment: @the_critic and how do you subscribe from the client side to a channel that you won't know in advance? I mean how do you subscribe to it?

Comment: You can send an id as params for connection.

Answer (score 7):

[kevinhyunilkim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39033585/683157)
is almost ok, but prefix depends on channel_name, not model class.

```
class CommentsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_for article
    # is equivalent to
    stream_from "#{self.channel_name}:{article.to_gid_param}"
    # in this class this means
    stream_from "comments:{article.to_gid_param}"
  end

  private

  # any activerecord instance has 'to_gid_param'
  def article
    Article.find_by(id: params[:article_id])
  end
end
```

you can also pass simple string to `stream_for` which simply adds channel name.

Answer (score 0):

`stream_for` takes an object as argument

```
class UserChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_for current_user
  end
end
```

`stream_from` takes a string as an argument

```
class ChatChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "chat_channel_#{params[:id]}"
  end
end
```

check this [article](http://laithazer.com/blog/2017/03/25/rails-actioncable-stream-for-vs-stream-from/) it deals with the concept very well in my opinion